# How can i create a function that outputs the amount of 0s in an array, within this code?

Tags: c++, integer

```
const int DECLARED_SIZE = 20;

void fillArray(int a[], int size, int& numberUsed) {
        cout << "Enter up to " << size << " nonnegative whole numbers.\n"
        << "Mark the end of the list with a negative number.\n";

    int next, index = 0;
    cin >> next;
    while ((next >= 0) && (index < size))
    {
        a[index] = next;
        index++;
        cin >> next;
    }

    numberUsed = index;
}

int search(const int a[], int numberUsed, int target)
{
    int index = 0;
    bool found = false;
    while ((!found) && (index < numberUsed))
        if (target == a[index])
            found = true;
        else
            index++;

    if (found)
        return index;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

It always outputs 0 for some reason.

```
int findZero(const int a[], int target, int numberUsed, int zeroes)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < numberUsed; index++)
        {
            if (target == a[index])
                zeroes++;
        }
        return zeroes;
    }
```

And this is the main code.

```
int main()
    {
    int arr[DECLARED_SIZE], listSize, target;
```

looks like post is mostly code
please add more details

```
fillArray(arr, DECLARED_SIZE, listSize);

    char ans;
    int result;
    int zeroes;
    int numberUsed;
    do
    { 
        cout << "Enter a number to search for: ";
        cin >> target;
        int numberOfZeroes = findZero(arr, target, zeroes, numberUsed);
        cout << "The amount of zero = " << zeroes << endl;
```

There is more to the code but i've only included that part where i need to output the amount of 0s in the array.

Comment: Do you have any idea why my function at the end keeps outputting 0? I am trying to get it to count and add up the total amount 0s in the array. So frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Number of elements in array (readed, not maximal size of array)

And why it is not counting correctly? Well you've switched parameters...

```
    int main()
    {
        int arr[DECLARED_SIZE], listSize;

        fillArray(arr, DECLARED_SIZE, listSize);

        int target;
        do {
            cout << "Enter a number to search for: ";
            target = -1; // if you give wrong input to cin, it will end (at least)
            cin >> target;
            int numberOfZeroes = findZero(arr, target, listSize, 0);
            cout << "The amount of number = " << numberOfZeroes << endl;
        } while (target >= 0);
        return 0;
    }
```

Why was zeroes passed there anyways? If you need local variable, create it as int zeroes = 0; That =0 is really important!

Comment: Thanks! Although im still unable to make my function work. I am trying to make a function that counts how and adds up many 0s are in the array.

I've edited my post at the end with the function that doesn't work. Any idea why it only outputs 0 no matter what the elements or array size is?

Comment: Don't you mean greater than or equal to 0?

Comment: Sorry, I'm sometimes like blind. Anyway how is your findZero called? Do you use return value? Or you try to use passed value and wonder why it's not working?

Comment: I've included the main() code at the end of my post.

Comment: So why don't you try to print `numberOfZeroes` instead of `zeroes` in cout? Also `int zeroes;` is not initialized, it might be anything.

Comment: Originally, i did. Still outputs 0.

edit: oh, any idea what i need to do?